# Infopath required attachment?

Tags: infopath

In InfoPath, how can you force a form to require an attachment every time it is saved? I have tried multiple solutions suggested on the web, including some from your site.  These all involved an extra text field with a rule.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use an extra administrator field to monitor the attachment field, because you can do more with it. But to answer your question, just put a Validation rule on your attachment field.

and the condition is "AttachmentField is Blank"